# Ways to create smart parameter passing in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit new to javascript, I'd like my function to take in parameters and associate 
them by name,

```
myFunction(width = 50, height = 20);
myFunction(height = 20, width = 20)
myFunction(width = 50); // height will get some default value
```

so then I can have:

```
  function myFunction()
  {
     var width; // this will somehow get the variable that was passed in or set default value
     var height; // this will somehow get the variable that was passed in or set default value
  }
```

Is there a way to possibly do this in javascript?

Also, I've seen syntax of the form

```
ball: {     
         x: '124',
         y: '22',
      }
```

but I have no idea what it's called.

Maybe I could use this syntax somehow, and create some kind of object that I then pass into my function.

But what I'm looking for is:

1. Pass parameters into a function by name, not by order.
2. Make all parameters passed into the function optional; if they are not passed in assign a default value.

What's the best/cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing an object as single parameter is the way to go.

Example:

```
function func(options) {
    var width = options.width || 0;
    var height = options.height || 0;
    //...
}

func({height: 100}); // width will be 0 as options.width is undefined
```

The `||` shorthand (boolean OR) will set each value to `0` if it is not provided. That is, it will assign `0` if `options.width` evaluates to `false` which is the case when it is not defined (i.e. `options.width` is `undefined`).

Whether this is sufficient depends on what kind of values are allowed. E.g. if `false` is a valid value, you have to explicitly test for `undefined`.

Another and arguably more handy way to define default values would be to use an `extend` function:

```
function extend(a, b) {
    for(var prop in b) {
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !a.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            a[prop] = b[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

This copies all properties of object `b` to object `a` if they are not present.

It lets you set default values this way

```
function func(options) {
     extend(options, {width: 0, height: 0});
     // access the values with options.height and options.width
     // options.height is not overwritten
}
```

regardless of the value.

---

This is the way jQuery uses. It provides an [`$.extend` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function which is commonly used when developing plugins to provide default settings. A good example of a function which accepts named and optional parameters is [`$.ajax` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a JS object to your function:

```
function myFunction(data) {
  var width = data.width;
  var height = data.height;

}

myFunction({'width':50, 'height':20});
```

Comment: There is no JSON in the question.

Comment: `ball: { x: '124', y: '22' }` looks like JSON to me am I missing something?

Comment: @FelixKling JSON is the answer to "what this syntax is called"

Comment: No, that is a JavaScript object literal. JSON would be `{"ball": {"x": "124", "y": "22"}}` (note the quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You would create an object literal and pass it as a parameter to the function:

```
var param = {
    x: 10,
    y: 20
}
```

pass it to your function:

```
foo(param);
```

and in your function code refer to is like so (for example):

```
function foo(param)
{
    console.log(param.x);
    console.log(param.y);
}
```

On your second question - passing parameters to the functions **is** optional in JavaScript - the parameters that didn't get passed would be `undefined` - that is not have value, but when accessed return `undefined`. Same goes for undefined properties of your `param` object - had you not defined `x` - `param.x` would return `undefined` upon access.